# Outdated path for module script

Tags: python, import, arcgis

I have a python script, running in ArcGIS, that evidently tries to import a module from an outdated location. I get an error message including traceback info:

```
File "x://outdated_path/SDMmodlue.py", line 25, in appendSDMValues ....etc
```

However, the module script `SDMmodule.py` is no longer in that location, and I did not find a reason why it tries to find it from there. The module script `SDMmodule.py` is now in the same directory as the main script; a totally different location. Can it be a Python matter, or is it more a problem with ArcGIS?

Comment: You need to post the full traceback :)

Comment: How did you delete the outdated file? Python did found the file and imported it, otherwise you would've get a "ImportError: no module named SDSmodule" error